# Thai character getting converted to Question mark

Tags: java, json, rest, encoding

I have a 3rd party api, which is giving me some json response

```
{
"name": "บรีส",
"company": "Таиланд",
}
```

In above Json response I have some Thai characters,
when I directly access the api I am getting the correct thai characters, but when I call it from my RestClient I am getting That character as ????

```
{
"name":"????????????",
"company":"??????????????"
}
```

Here is my RestClient Code

```
private void executeRequest(HttpUriRequest request,    String url) throws CommonException, IOException{
    //logger.debug(CLASS_NAME+" executeRequest : Entry :: url ->"+url + " Request: "+ postData );
    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
               .setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeOut)
               .setConnectionRequestTimeout(soTimeOut)
               .setSocketTimeout(soTimeOut)
               .build();

    CloseableHttpClient client;

        client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                .useSystemProperties().build();

    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = null  ;
    InputStream instream = null;
    try {
        httpResponse = client.execute(request, localContext);
        responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        message = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();
        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            instream = entity.getContent(); 
            response = convertStreamToString(instream);
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        //logger.debug(CLASS_NAME+" :: executeRequest : ClientProtocolException :: url ->"+url+ " responseCode -> " +  responseCode + "message -> " + message  + " Service Execution Rime: "+lSvcExecTime+"\n  Request -> "+postData + "  Exception : "+ e.getMessage() );
        throw e; 
    }catch (SocketException e) {
        //logger.debug(CLASS_NAME+" :: executeRequest : SocketException :: url ->"+url+ " responseCode -> " +  responseCode + "message -> " + message  + " Service Execution Rime: "+lSvcExecTime+"\n  Request -> "+postData + "  Exception : "+ e.getMessage() );
        throw e; 

    } finally {
        if(httpResponse!=null){
            httpResponse.close();
        }
        if(null != instream){
            instream.close();
        }
    }
}

private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        try {
            while((length = is.read(buffer)) != -1){
                result.write(buffer,0,length);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //logger.error(CLASS_NAME+" IOException due to - "+e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //logger.error(CLASS_NAME+"IOException inside finally due to - "+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        log.warning("Response in RestClient ---"+result.toString());
        //return result.toString();
        return new String(result.toString().getBytes(), "UTF-8");
}
```

This code perfectly run in my local system but when I run this code at server it gives me ????.

Note : when calling RestClient I am adding header -

```
        client.AddHeader("Content-Type","application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

Please guide me what to do.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I am converting streamArray to string and sending it to caller method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this expression

```
new String(result.toString().getBytes(), "UTF-8")
```

to

```
new String(result.toByteArray(), "UTF-8")
```

By first converting `result` to a string and then back to bytes, you are converting the data using the JVM's default charset, which is presumably UTF-8 on your local machine, but not on your server.

---

A couple of observations:

- You should look carefully at the setup of you JVM in production: set the default encoding to a value you intend, e.g. UTF-8, so you are not surprised by it using non-UTF-8.
- You don't need to read into a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, and then convert to a `String` afterwards: wrap the `InputStream` in an `InputStreamReader` (specifying the charset) and a `BufferedReader`: then you can read the chars directly, and append them to, say, a `StringBuilder`.